# Complex CakePHP data return and combining

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, sql-order-by

I am aiming to create a summary page of activity on an application I am currently working on. I have identified that I must do the following:

Get all stories from people I am subscribed to and format them like the following:

```
[Username] has posted [StoryName] - View story
```

Get all stories that users I am connected to have posted comments on

```
[Username] has posted a comment on [StoryName] - View story
```

I am unsure how I can get both arrays, display them the format I want but order them by the posted date (in the same way people like Facebook do)

What is the best way to go about this?

Please Note: The answer must be something which is easily extendible. I am considering following wordpress' model and creating a Posts table which has a Post Type field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're trying to do is pretty much built-in with CakePHP.  The big thing is to make sure that your models are properly associated.  Once this is accomplished, Cake will do most of the heavy lifting for you.

For your situation, use 3 models associated like this:

```
class Story extends AppModel{
    var $belongsTo = 'Author';
    var $hasMany = 'Comment';
}

class Author extends AppModel{
    var $hasMany = array( 'Story', 'Comment' );
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = 'User';
}

class Comment extends AppModel{
    var $belongsTo = array( 'Author', 'Story' );
}
```

Set up your tables according to the Cake conventions.  Then a little CakePHP magic in your controller:

```
$this->Story->Author->bindModel( array( 'hasOne' => array( 'AuthorsUsers' ) ) );
$myAuthors = $this->Story->Author->find( 'list', array(
    'fields' => array( 'id' ),
    'conditions' => array( 'AuthorsUsers.user_id' => $userId ),
    'recursive' => false 
    ) );

$stories = $this->Story->find( 'all', array(
    'fields' => array( 'Story.id', 'Story.title', 'Author.id', 'Author.name' ),
    'order' => 'published_date DESC',
    'conditions' => array( 'Author.id' => $myAuthors ),
    'recursive' => 2
    ) );
```

Quick explanation of what's going on:

- [`bindModel()`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM) lets Cake know that you want to use the HABTM association to find Authors by the associated User id.  (Cake convention is to have a table called 'authors_users' to join the Author->User HABTM association.)
- If you debug the `$myAuthors` variable, you'll see that it gets a simple array of ids.
- `'conditions' => array( 'field' => array() )` will get parsed as "WHERE field IN (...)".  In this example, we get all models `WHERE 'Author.id' IN $myAuthors`.
- The short `$this->Story->find()` call is the beauty of Cake.  It will automatically find all Story models matching the specified conditions, *and* it will find the other models associated with each found Story.  (You can tell it not to find associated models by turning off [Recursive](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1063/recursive) or using [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable) behavior.)
- Debugging the `$stories` variable will show you a structure like the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Story] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [title] => 'Common Sense'
                    [published_date] => 1776-01-10 
                )
            [Author] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => 'Thomas Paine'
                )
            [Comment] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [text] => 'Revolutionary!'
                            [Author] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 3
                                    [name] => 'Silence Dogood'
                                )
                        )
                    [1...n] => ...
                )
        )
    [1...n] => ...
)
```

You can then use that structure in your View to display data as you desire.

I have a feeling there should be a way to do it with just 1 query, but this way works and doesn't require you to do any subqueries or insert custom SQL into your Cake `find()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Gary, it is difficult to answer this without knowing your models. Assuming you have got correctly defined schema and models it should be relatively easy.

For your find queries order by date DESC and retrieve the last 10 rows. (this would give you last 20 results for example)

Merge the result sets into one and sort by date DESC again. It's then some trivial rendering logic to render the strings as you need.

Comment: I do have correctly defined models with relations etc, I was thinking on something along this path also, to me it seems the easiest way would to be to write the rendering logic then combine the arrays, but I really don't want to have a big lump of html in my arrays. Ideally I would have some way to differentiate a story which a user has commented on, and a story which a user has posted (Even though I am just pulling the story out on each occasion)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would do something like this

Create the following Relationships

User **hasMany** StoryName

User **hasMany** Comments

StoryName **hasMany** Comments

Comments **belongsTo** User

Comments **belongsTo** StoryName

That way would be really easy to retrieve all the information needed, since you could fetch all the needed data though the User model with something like

```
$this->User->recursive = 2;

$this->User->find('all', $params) *// on $params you could use the conditions that the user retrieved should be friends to the current user*
```

Hopefully that would give me an Array populated with the following structure

[USER]
  [POSTS]
  [COMMENTS]

And was just a matter of passing it to the view and using a foreach in the view to create the Html

Comment: This is how I have set my models and such up just now. But I am still unsure on how I would display the data the way that I want as there is no identifier which tells me if the user posted a story or a comment

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you you already have other models setup (User, Story, etc.). But to keep the answer to the point, I'll just focus on Activity model (activities table): You can use this table like a log table.

A simple table: id, user_id, story_id, created (datetime), action_type(0 for post story, 1 for comment on a story, for example). Then it's simply a matter of querying this table to find the activities.

Or a more generic, extensible one: id, subject_id, subject_type (User or whatever is acting), verb_type, object_id, object_type, created. You don't really have to bind this model to any other model (Although you can with the 'conditions' when you specify relationship) or bindModel on the fly.